# How to convert a continuous numbered array into a timestamp

Tags: python-3.x

I am gathering data on a device, and after every second, I update a count and log it. I am now processing it, and am new to python, so I had a question as to whether it was possible to convert a numbered array `[0,1,2,3,4,...1091,1092,1093,...]` into a timestamp `[00:00:01, 00:00:02, 00:00:03, 00:00:04, ... 00:18:11, 00:18:12, 00:18:13,...]` for example.

If you could please lead me in the right direction, that would be very much appreciated!

p.s. In the future, I will be logging the data as a timestamp, but for now, I have 5 hours' worth of data that needs to be processed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import datetime as dt
timestamp=[0,1,2,3,4,5,1092,1093]
print([dt.timedelta(seconds=ts) for ts in timestamp])
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 1):

If all you have is seconds, then you can just do simple arithmetic to convert them to minutes and hours:

```
inp = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1091, 1092, 1093]
outp = [f'{secs // 3600:02}:{(secs // 60) % 60:02}:{secs % 60:02}' for secs in inp]
print(outp)
# ['00:00:00', '00:00:01', '00:00:02', '00:00:03', '00:00:04', '00:18:11', '00:18:12', '00:18:13']
```

Here, I use a list comprehension and, for each `secs` in the input, create a format string:

- hours is `secs // 3600` (that's integer floor division), because one hour is 3600 seconds
- Minutes is `(secs // 60) % 60` (this incorporates the modulo operator, which displays the remainder of `secs // 60` after dividing it by 60 again). One minute is 60 seconds, but more than 60 minutes would be an hour, so we need to make sure to 'roll over' the counter every 60 minutes (which is what the mod is for).
- Seconds is, of course, `secs % 60`, because a minute has 60 seconds and we want the counter to roll over.

The format string starts with `f'`, and anything inside `{}` is an instruction to evaluate whatever's inside it, and insert that into the string. The syntax is `{expression:format}`, where `display` is an optional instruction for how to format the data (i.e. not just printing it out). And `format` can get complicated (look up a python f-string tutorial if you're curious about the specifics), but suffice it to say that in this case we use `02`, which means that we want the output to be two characters in length, and padded with zeroes in case it's less than that.